# how to find data under other data in sql with cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, aggregation

i have a table like:

```
create table police(
ssn
name
boss_name
salary
);

Insert into police values(1,’A’,’C’,10000);
Insert into police values(2,’B’,’D’,20000);
Insert into police values(3,’C’,’E’,30000);
Insert into police values(4,’D’,’E’,45000);
Insert into police values(5,’E’,NULL,55000);
```

I want a `cursor` that returns the `total salary` for the `polices who have same boss`. Here result will be: 
`30000(salary of C)+45000(salary of D)` 
as they both are under boss E. How I do it? How I find C and D as they are under E in ORACLE pl/sql or anonymous block?

Comment: Thats the basic sql,you can use group by .Your cursor query will be like  `select boss_name,sum(salary) from police group by boss_name`.

Comment: Reg: "how I find C and D as they are under E in ORACLE pl/sql or anonymous block".. this is like report .. and depending on the format in which you want .. what is the output you are looking for?

Comment: @pratikgarg:You can use analytical function for that ,`sum(salary) over (partition by boss_name order by ssn) total_salary`

Comment: If you wanted is a GROUP BY this is a really simple SQL question.  Oracle has some good documentation, including an introduction aimed at developers.  I suggest you have a look at it.  Here is the section on aggregation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_selecting.htm#BCGJDGBA

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
 cboss_name varchar2(30) ;
 csalary number ;  
 CURSOR cur
 is       
  select boss_name,sum(salary)  as salary
  from police 
  where boss_name is not null 
  group by boss_name;
begin
   open cur;
   fetch cur into cboss_name,csalary;
    dbms_output.put_line('boss_name'||' '||'csalary');
    LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO cboss_name,csalary;
       EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
       dbms_output.put_line(cboss_name||'         '||csalary);
   END LOOP;

   close cur;  
end;
```

[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php) you can find more information about cursors and loops.

Comment: Besides the unnecessary use of PL/SQL this does not roll up the salaries of junior staff into totals for bosses.

Comment: @Mahade Hasan I'm glad I could help you :)

Comment: Fair enough - I thought the question was less trivial than it turned out to be.

Answer (score 2):

Gaurav Soni and APC gave good advice in their comments.

General rule of thumb - don't use a cursor for things that can be solved easily with straight SQL. The straight SQL is typically much faster.

The following SQL will list each boss, the total salary of direct reports, and the count of direct reports.

```
select boss_name,
       sum(salary) total_salary,
       count(*) employee_count
  from police
 where boss_name is not null
 group by boss_name
```

You can certainly use the above query to define your cursor if you need to iterate the boss's. But you should not use a cursor to compute the totals. Let SQL do the work.